# how can I make append function work after window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, window.location

I would like to change my webpage from one to another with passing a value by clicking a button, so I can pass the value into another function. Here are some codes.

```
<button onclick="review('${num}')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">see reviews</button>
```

```
function review(val) {
    window.location.href = '/review'
    console.log(val)
    let temp_html = `<button onclick="showReviewTable(${val})" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">review</button>`
    $('#make-review').append(temp_html);
}
```

```
function showReviewTable(val) {
    console.log(val)
}
```

The problem is append function is not changing anything in review function (but it changes if it is in a different function..). console.log(val) value in review disappears so fast on the console and the value in showReviewTable shows undefined.

How can I make append work and pass the value successfully?

I have tried to use window.stop. At this time, I could get the console.log(val) value on the console in review function, but it did not direct to the new page. I have also tried to use e.preventDefault(), but still no luck.

Comment: That is impossible. When you navigate away you are replacing the page. The code can not execute on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as `window.location.href = ...` executes, none of the reset of your code will function because that page will be unloaded and a new one loaded.

You could add a querystring to the URL that you are navigating to and then ON THAT PAGE, have a script the reads the querystring and does the work for that page.

You could also set a value into `localStorage` just before navigating to the second page and ON THAT PAGE read the `localStorage` value and act based on that.